# What is the difference between *array[] and array[]?

Tags: c++, arrays

- As we know that the value of array name is the address of the first element in the array
- and the Value of the pointer is an address .

Suppose I declare a pointer to an int

```
int *a= new int(); 
int *b= new int();
```

And I want it to store its address in some array but the array will not be the pointer like this

```
int *arr[] = {a, b};
```

And is it possible ?

because the array name contain the address and if we declare an array pointer then they will again contain the address same thing ,

- so how can we store a pointers in regular array and not a pointer
  array  . 
  like

  ```
  int arr[] = {a,b} ; //not like int arr[] = {*a, *b};
  ```

and If not so why ?

Comment: *so how can we store a pointers in regular array and not a pointer array* It's not clear to me what you mean by that.

Comment: https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*arr%5B%5D vs https://cdecl.org/?q=int+arr%5B%5D

Comment: "but the array will not be the pointer like this" -- why not?  If you tried and it didn't work, what was the error message?

Comment: Use a `std::array<int*,2>` in that case.

Comment: there is no error scott Hunter but i think if it is possible or not . I am simply asking that .

Comment: You may need to clarify what you mean when you say that some arrays are "regular arrays".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understant that what are you asking about ?
i think you say that!

1.What is the difference between Pointer array and normal array.

2.why we can't assign pointer to normal array something like this :

```
int *a= new int(); 
int *b= new int();

int SomeArray[] = {a,b} // and you trying to saying that why this is compiler error. while putting the a,b pointer into a normal array.

int *SomeArray[] = {a,b} // it is valid. because it is pointer array to in Int and contain pointers to in Int variables.
```

So i think is something you trying to ask.

**Conclusion:**
If you declare a normal or regular array of a specific type, then you have to the appropriate value that.
and if the array is Pointer array then you must have put pointer's in it.

for example:

```
//For pointer array.

int *a= new int(); // this is pointer to an Int a.
int *b= new int(); // this is pointer to an Int b.

int *pointerArray[]={a,b};

//For regular array.

int x= 10; // this is normal int.
int y= 20; // this is normal int.

int normalArray[]={x,y};
```

I hope what you trying to asking about. You Got it right ?

Answer (score 5):

```
int *arr[] = {a, b};
```

does not declare a pointer, it declares an array of pointers whose size is determined by the *braced-init-list*.  This is the syntax that you want if you want a raw array of raw pointers.

That said, manual memory management is fraught with complications and a `std::unique_ptr<int>[]`, `std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>, some_compile_time_size>`, or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` should be preferred since they will manage releasing the memory when they go out of scope.